# List sort() vs own sort() Time Difference

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, mergesort

I have question about that;

I have a class like that

```
class myCLass {
    private:
        string name;
        float value;
    public:
        float getValue();
};
```

I have more than 1,000,000 objects and I have to sort that items according to its value. So I created that pointer list;

```
list<myClass *> objectList;
```

then filled it with more than 1.000.000 objects. Now you can say that vector is best way if your object smaller than 30-40 bits it is absolutely true anyway then I created that;

```
bool ec(myClass *s1, myClass *s2) 
{
    return (s1->getValue() < s2->getValue());
}
```

then in main function;

```
time = clock();
objectList.sort(ec);    // Sort with STL.
time = clock() - time;
cout << ((float)time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\t:time to sort" << endl;
```

and it takes only 1.2 second! it is incredible for me and remember that it is list container which is slowest way may be vector can be more effective :) anyway my question is that I wrote an insertionSort and mergeSort algorithm and if someone use my sorting algorithm and if s/he want to short 1 million object it takes 3 hours, yes 3 hours :) and i wonder why it is more that it. And I use general algorithm for merge and insertion not different thing and they calculate true result. For example my insertionSort() like that;

```
void sort::insertionSort(list<myClass *> &normalList, list<myClass *> &sortedList){

    list<myClass*>::iterator sortedIterator;

    sortedList.clear();
    iter = normalList.begin(); // iter describing on constructor
    sortedList.push_back(*iter);
    iter++;

    for(; iter != normalList.end(); iter++){

        sortedIterator = (--sortedList.end());

        while( (*iter)->getValue() < (*sortedIterator)->getValue() && sortedIterator!=(--sortedList.begin() ) ){
        sortedIterator--;
        }
        sortedList.insert(++sortedIterator,*iter);
    }
}
```

benchmark table for my insertionSort();

```
n=10      => 0      second;
n=100     => 0      second;
n=1.000   => 0      second;
n=10.000  => 0.96   second;
n=20.000  => 4.73   seconds;
n=50.000  => 34.22  seconds;
n=100.000 => 306.62 seconds
```

I could not control for more than 100.000 :)

So is it normal or I had a mistake?

Note: I try with vector for insertion sort and for n=100.000 time is 50 seconds so still I could not reach 1.29 second despite n=100.000 not 1.000.000 :)

Note 2: This is the benchmark for mergeSort();

```
n=10      => 0      second;
n=100     => 0      second;
n=1.000   => 0.02      second;
n=10.000  => 0.8   second;
n=20.000  => 3.07   seconds;
n=50.000  => 21.7  seconds;
n=100.000 => 106.73 seconds
```

Comment: Experience/knowledge and compiler intrinsics.

Comment: Yes, insertion sort is a lot slower than sorting methods used in libraries, like mergesort and quicksort. You say you also implemented mergesort, what were the results for that? Also, what does your mergesort look like?

Comment: Note that your version creates a copy of the list too... The sort is not 'in place'.

Comment: Time complexity (worst case) for Insertion Sort is roughly O(n²).

Comment: Remember that sorting times for different algorithms vary by the order of the original data. Presorted data has one timing that may be different than data sorted in opposite order.

Comment: @Jarod42 Regardless of how he implements it, he will have to copy (reconstruct) nodes; the standard `std::list<>::sort` has access to the internals of the list, including the pointers within each node, and can do a lot by pointer arithmetic where he will end up copying.  (Or perhaps he could approach what the standard function does using `list.splice`; I've not looked at it in detail.)

Comment: And while I'm at it: `--sortedList.end()` is not guaranteed to compile.  Use `std::prev( sortedList.end() )` (or an equivalent from your toolbox if you don't have C++11).

Comment: @JamesKanze: In his case, he may swap value (the pointer) to avoid copy. I just wanted to highlight that it is not a fair comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Insert sort is asymptotically slower than the build-in algorithm. While insert sort has a complexity of `O(n^2)` the built-in algorithm has a complexity `O(n*log(n))` by standard. Thus the more elements you have the slower your algorithm will be in comparison to built-in sort algorithm.

It is almost never worth it to implement your own sorting algorithm as the built-in implementation is already very optimized.

Comment: It's almost certainly merge sort, and not introsort; introsort requires random access iterators, where as `std::list` only has bidirectional iterators.

Comment: No, of course `std::list` sort is not introsort. I have removed this bit as it is not true for lists. I did not read the question carefully enough. Thank you

Comment: I know that complexity but i believe that although it is O(n^2) it does not take a long time to calculate it. And if there are stl merge or stl insertion sort it will not take 3  hours to calculate. 
Although i made an mergeSort() and running time is still more than it. I wonder if a stl insertion sort or merge sort can do it more quickly or not?

Comment: @user2879337 There is no STL insertion sort.  `std::sort` on a container with random access iterators (e.g. `std::vector` or `std::deque`) will use either quick sort or intro sort (generally, although it can legally use heap sort); `std::list<>::sort` will use merge sort, manipulating the pointers directly so that there will be no new nodes created.

Answer (score 2):

Algorithmic theory tells you that an insertion sort has a complexity **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** whereas a quicksort has complexity **O(n log(n))**. For a large data set this is a substantial difference; loosely speaking your algorithm will be **n / log(n)** times slower.

That difference can get gigantic when you consider the effect of taking the logarithm of a number: if you take the base 10 logarithm of the number of particles in the universe, the answer is about 87.

Comment: Quicksort has a _best case_ complexity of O(n lg n).  And a worst case of O(n^2).  Typically, it's not far from the best case for random data, but degenerate cases do exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your version is basically constructs the sorted list into a new
list.  While you're only copying pointers, you are still doing
a new allocation, etc. for each node.  Presumably, the member
function sort never creates or deletes a node; it operates by
changing the pointers between existing nodes.  (And of course,
there's no insertion sort involved; it will be a pure merge
sort.)

Comment: `it will be a pure merge sort` don't the built in C++ sort functions combine several algorithms? i.e. `sort` using not only merge sort algorithm?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie What other algorithm is effective when sorting a list?

Comment: While 1.000.000 elements sorting i have allocated 1.000.000 pointers allocation and it is very quick to do that any way I try to sorting on same list and also i use vector but result is not different :(

Comment: @JamesKanze that is why I ask.

Comment: @user2879337 Insertion sort is not particularly efficient.